# Unity - Inconsistant speed of object following raycast2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, path, rotation, raycasting

So im creating a simple game and one component of the game is a greendot following the outside of the level. I got this working using a raycast in the middle which rotates and gives the position of collision the the gameobject.

[game overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igQr.png)

The problem is that the speed is inconsistant at the moment since the distance between two collisions can be further distance if i have a slope. I also have the feeling that there should be a easier way to get the same result. What are your thoughts?

```
public class FollowPath : MonoBehaviour {
        Vector3 collisionPos;
        public GameObject greenDot;

        void Update ()
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up);
            transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 3);

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                collisionPos = hit.point;
            }

            greenDot.transform.position = collisionPos;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you will like this answer, as it suggests a complete departure from the way you were trying to do it.

A simple way to do this, would be to give your moving dot GameObject a [Rigidbody2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) component, AND a [CircleCollider](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CircleCollider2D.html) component.

Then, make your walls, and add to each an EdgeCollider component.

You'll probably also want to add a PhysicsMaterial2d to each GameObject with a Collider and set the friction and bounciness values for each.

Once this is setup, you can apply an initial force to the rigid body ball to get it moving, and it will bounce off the walls just like a ball does, using the Unity physics engine.  No code would be needed in you update functions.